# Dados de conexão de banco de dados nas perguntas?

Tags: debate

Um colega de trabalho que também faz parte do stackoverlow me mostrou uma pergunta em que existiam dados para conexão do banco de dados do usuário.
Com os dados lá presentes fica evidente que é possível fazer a conexão.

Qual é o procedimento para tais perguntas visto que nem mesmo a edição torna-a segura (para o usuário), já que os dados da conexão do usuário ainda estão no histórico de edição da pergunta?

Comment: Neste caso o @lbotinelly realizou as alterações para não mostrar os dados, mas os mesmos ainda constam no histórico de edições. Não vi alguma funcionalidade para isso, mas sinalizei a pergunta para atenção dos moderadores

Comment: O óbvio é sinalizar. Mas não resolve. Precisa ter alguma forma de resolver logo este tipo de coisa. Não pode levar o tempo que leva para uma ação ser feita.

Comment: Pois é, e o pior é que dá pra conectar com o banco mesmo.  Foi só um teste pra poder verificar a gravidade disso.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2358/91

Comment: O pior é que nem os moderadores conseguem apagar o histórico, precisa de um CM, tornando a ação mais demorada ainda.

Comment: @Math a solução (na minha opnião) é deletar a pergunta, copiar, e criar outra

Comment: @WallaceMaxters depende da situação, se já tivesse respostas essa ação provavelmente não funcionaria tão bem, e mesmo que não tivesse, deletar não impede que os usuários com 10K+ a vejam.

Comment: @Math dificilmente alguém com mais de 10k seria mal intecionado ;). Se não outra cacas poderiam acontecer pelo fato de ele ser tão "Poderoso" no site

Comment: @WallaceMaxters de qualquer forma, preferi apagar para deixar menos visível pelo menos por enquanto. Deixei também um comentário instruindo o usuário a criar uma nova pergunta e mudar a senha dele.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ninguém te garante isso. Alguém com mais de 10k pode ser maldoso e usar a informação indevidamente. Apagar a pergunta só resolveria o problema em parte.

Comment: @Math o melhor seria ver com o Gabe o que fazer nesses casos.

Comment: @JorgeB. já falei, mas até ele responder acho que é melhor deixar a pergunta apagada mesmo.

Comment: Independente da remoção, o usuário precisa ser avisado para mudar as coisas do lado dele, pois essa informação pode ter sido "eternizada" por algum _crawler_. (vide comment que eu deixei em uma ocorrência anterior desse tipo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2358#comment7929_2360 )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A primeira coisa é **não expor ainda mais a pergunta**, dando o link de bandeja aqui no Meta ಠ_ಠ

Dito isso, como vocês podem ver no [histórico dessa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4651/revisions), é possível apagar informações de posts sem deixar registro de edição, mas apenas funcionários do Stack Overflow podem fazer isso.

O problema óbvio é que 15 pessoas - os CMs<sup>1</sup> - agem mais devagar que centenas, e isso é um problema quando o assunto é segurança. Por outro lado, permitir que mais pessoas possam fazer edições invisíveis *também* é um risco. São riscos diferentes, e que não tem nenhuma bala de prata pra resolver.

Sempre que há um caso desses, eu resolvo o mais rápido possível. Hoje, infelizmente, aconteceu quando eu não estava trabalhando, e a pergunta ficou lá por muito mais tempo que o devido.

O Math fez muito bem em apagá-la. A melhor coisa em casos assim, principalmente antes de serem resolvidos, é diminuir ao máximo a visibilidade da pergunta, evitando expô-la.

Conversei com os moderadores sobre levar casos assim, ou qualquer outra coisa, aos outros CMs sempre que eles julgarem necessário. Nosso site é parte de uma rede, e tem tanto acesso à todos os recursos da empresa quanto qualquer outro.

Quanto à comunidade, coisas assim devem ser tratadas como foram hoje:

- Uma edição diminui a visibilidade do conteúdo comprometido, mesmo que não apague totalmente do histórico.
- Sinalização na pergunta, para chamar atenção dos moderadores. Eles podem apagar comentários que indicam o problema (de novo, para evitar chamar a atenção) e entrar em contato com os CMs para resolver o problema o mais rápido possível.

---

<sup>1. Se é que ainda somos 15... eu perdi a conta</sup>

Comment: Gabe então podemos comunicar a um qualquer CM o problema ou comunicamos somente ao CM do site em questão?

Comment: @JorgeB. Qualquer CM. Na maioria das vezes eu vou poder resolver muito mais rápido já que estou aqui pra isso. Mas, como aconteceu ontem, pode ser que eu não esteja disponível... Então vocês tem total liberdade para chamar qualquer outro CM

Comment: @Gabe só pra completar a discussão, há alguma via expressa (email, qq coisa do tipo) pra encaminhar essas coisas, paralelamente à sinalização, ou é melhor não inventar?

Comment: Tá que a dúvida não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas o que é um CM?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Community Manager (Gerente de comunidade)

Comment: @Bacco Pings no chat funcionam muito bem, especialmente para o [Shog9](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6/shog9), [Tim Post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/10/tim-post), [Jon Ericsson](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4/jon-ericson) ou o [JNat](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat) que fala português e pode facilitar bastante.